# How to add mesh primitives in Blender Python using data blocks

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

In Blender Python I can add a lamp by doing the following:

```
DataBlock = bpy.data.lamps.new(name='HemiA', type='HEMI')
ObjHandle = bpy.data.objects.new(name='HemiA', object_data=DataBlock)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(ObjHandle)
```

I want to do the same for mesh primitives such as Suzanne. There is an operator for this: `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()`, however there doesn't seem to be any way to create a mesh primitive data block.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if there are functions which return mesh primitives as a data block in the Blender API. But you can create a Suzanne data block by using a `bmesh` and [`bmesh.ops.create_monkey(bm, matrix)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.70/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.create_monkey) which you can then convert to a mesh data block

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_monkey(bm)

# Create mesh data block from bmesh
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Mesh')
bm.to_mesh(mesh)
bm.free()

# Create object and link object to scene
obj = bpy.data.objects.new('Object', mesh)
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
bpy.context.scene.update()
```